# Prevent requests for css and js files to go through Dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Please can someone tell me how to prevent requests for css and js files to go through dispatcher, I'm using spring MVC, I'm getting "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI":

```
déc. 26, 2015 5:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Avertissement: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spr-mvc-hib/css/style2.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
déc. 26, 2015 5:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Avertissement: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spr-mvc-hib/css/style.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
déc. 26, 2015 5:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Avertissement: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spr-mvc-hib/predict_it.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
déc. 26, 2015 5:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Avertissement: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spr-mvc-hib/js/index.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
déc. 26, 2015 5:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Avertissement: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spr-mvc-hib/js/index1.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
déc. 26, 2015 5:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Avertissement: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spr-mvc-hib/predict_it.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

This is my config :

**WebAppConfig class :**

```
package com.sprhib.init;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sprhib")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));


        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**Initializer**

```
package com.sprhib.init;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        //ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        ctx.register(com.sprhib.init.WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

Here is more information :

[my project tree, I made resources in two locations,nothing works :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypcpw.jpg)

[Here is inspection on browser :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCcR4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to add resource handlers mapping for your static content to your dispatcher configuration. 
This will tell dispatcher to send the static resource in the response. Something like :

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
     .addResourceLocations("/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
     .addResourceLocations("/img/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
     .addResourceLocations("/js/");

}
```

Comment: thank you, this helped me not to have this error, but still css and js files do not load yet :( , this is the same question not answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276757/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-i) @Nighthacks

Comment: @YoussefElRhailani, check your resource path, if you are not getting any error that means mapping is right but your resource is not at correct location.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Nighthacks, I did all my best but in vain :\
I really tried all the possible location but with no result, thank you a lot =)

Comment: @YoussefElRhailani, did you see any error in browser console? probably i would be able to help if you can post your directory structure of your resources.

Comment: Thank you Nighthacks, I fixed the problem, I just wasn't using  "<c:url value='/resources/image/predict_it.png'/>" so it references to the root project... Thank you a lot for your help =)